# Slow state update in redux

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

So I have this problem where a variable update is slower than a route change.
When I have an error on for example my registration view, the error shows up instantly. When press back to come back to the login view, the error is being reset *(action "clearErrors" is being fired on componentWillUnmount)* to an empty string via an action. The problem is that I can se the error message on the login for a brief moment before it receives the new empty error state.

ErrorReducer.js

```
import {
    ERROR,
    CLR_ERROR
} from '../actions/types';

const INIT_STATE = {
    error: ''
};

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ERROR:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload };
        case CLR_ERROR:
            return { ...state, error: '' };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

error.js (actions)

```
import { CLR_ERROR } from './types';

export const clearErrors = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: CLR_ERROR });
    };
};
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser, resetRoute, autoLogin } from '../actions';
import { Button, Input, Message } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.resetRoute();
    }

    onEmailChange(text) {
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
    }

    onPasswordChange(text) {
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }

    onButtonPress() {
        this.props.loading = true;
        const { email, password } = this.props;
        this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    marginLeft: 10,
                    marginRight: 10,
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
                keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            >

                <Message
                    type="danger"
                    message={this.props.error}
                />

                <Input
                    placeholder="din@email.se"
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    returnKeyType="next"
                    onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.email}
                    icon="ios-mail"
                />
                <Input
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder="ditt lösenord"
                    onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.password}
                    icon="ios-key"
                    iconSize={22}
                />

                <Button
                    loading={this.props.loading}
                    uppercase
                    color="primary"
                    label="Logga in"
                    onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}
                />

                <Button
                    fontColor="primary"
                    label="Registrera"
                    onPress={() => Actions.register()}
                />
                <Button
                    fontColor="primary"
                    label="Glömt lösenord"
                    onPress={() => Actions.resetpw()}
                />

            </View>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth, errors }) => {
    const { email, password, loading, token } = auth;
    const { error } = errors;
    return { email, password, error, loading, token };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser, resetRoute, autoLogin
})(LoginForm);
```

Message.js (component to show error)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { colors } from '../style';

export const Message = ({ type, message }) => {
    const style = {
        view: {
            alignSelf: 'stretch',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 20,
            margin: 15,
            backgroundColor: colors[type],
            borderRadius: 3,
            elevation: 5,
            shadowRadius: 5,
            shadowColor: colors.smoothBlack,
            shadowOffset: { width: 2.5, height: 2.5 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.5
        },
        text: {
            color: colors.alternative,
            fontSize: 12,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            flex: 1
        },
        icon: {
            marginRight: 20,
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginTop: 2,
            alignSelf: 'center'
        }
    };
    const getIcon = (iconType) => {
        switch (iconType) {
            case 'info':
                return 'ios-information-circle';
            case 'success':
                return 'ios-checkmark-circle';
            case 'danger':
                return 'ios-alert';
            case 'warning':
                return 'ios-warning';
            default:
                return;
        }
    };
    if (message.length > 0) {
        return (
            <View style={style.view}>
                {(type) ? <Icon name={getIcon(type)} size={20} style={style.icon} /> : null}
                <Text style={style.text}>{message}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
    return <View />;
};
```

I am running on device OnePlus3 with all console.logs removed, production build.

From what I have read, this should be fast. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to say without looking at your rendering code, but it's likely that the slowness is not caused by the time it takes for redux to update the state, but for React to re-render the UI after the dispatch has completed - possibly because it's busy re-rendering other things while your navigator is transitioning.

To guarantee the ordering of actions with `redux-thunk`, you can return a Promise from your thunk action creator and wait to navigate back until the action has been dispatched:

```
export const clearErrors = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise(dispatch({ type: CLR_ERROR }));
    };
};
```

In your view then, you can do the back navigation action once the error has been cleared:

```
// assuming the action creator has been passed
// to the component as props
this.props.clearErrors().then(() => navigator.back());
```

Comment: My components has some binding in them. I recently read that that will make rendering slow, so maybe that is it then.
    onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}

Comment: I doubt that's the problem. The reason people warn against .bind() in render is that it creates unnecessary function instances, and possibly messes with the child component's shouldComponentUpdate checks. Neither are going to cause the perf issue here, and I've never seen anyone back their claims of .bind() causing slowness actually back it with real benchmarks.

Comment: I see.. I've updated my main post with some more code. LoginForm.js which is the component I'm navigating back to, that shows <Message/> component for a very brief moment. Would you mind taking a look?